change visualization format plotly bar plot
I want to change the visualization format from

(This is coded by python-plotly dash)
to

(This is not coded in python)
Here is the code for 1st visualization in python :
def viz_proba_cause(df):
    """
    Visualisation de probabilité de cause
    """
    df = df.sort_values(by='proba_cause',ascending=True)
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df['proba_cause'],
    y=df['failure_cause'],
    marker=dict(
        color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.6)',
        line=dict(
            color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 1.0)',
            width=1),
    ),
    name='Cause Probability',
    orientation='h',
))
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Cause Probability with symptome',
        )
    annotations = []



    # Adding labels
    for proba,state in zip(df['proba_cause'],df['failure_cause']):
        # labeling the bar net worth
        annotations.append(dict(
                                y=state, x=proba+0.02,
                                text=str(round(proba*100,2)) + '%',
                                font=dict(family='Arial', size=12,
                                        color='rgb(50, 171, 96)'),
                                showarrow=False))

    fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
    
    
    return fig

Can you help me to change the format ?
and If it is possible, I want to use gradation in terms of probability

There are a multitude of different ways to do this. Here is one with bars as you  described in the question:
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'failure_cause': ['Cause 1', 'Cause 2', 'Cause 3', 'Cause 4', 'Cause 5'],
    'proba_cause': [0.5767, 0.1923, 0.0648, 0.0502, 0.0502]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def generate_card(failure_cause, proba_cause, rank):
    bar_color = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)'  
    bar_line_color = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)' 

    return dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H4(f"{failure_cause}", className="card-title"),
                html.P(
                    f"{round(proba_cause*100, 2)}%",
                    className="card-text",
                ),
                html.P(
                    f"rank: {rank}",
                    className="card-text",
                ),
                dcc.Graph(
                    figure=go.Figure(go.Bar(
                        x=[proba_cause * 100],
                        y=[failure_cause],
                        orientation='h',
                        marker=dict(
                            color=bar_color,
                            line=dict(
                                color=bar_line_color,
                                width=1),
                        ),
                    )).update_layout(
                        xaxis=dict(range=[0, 100]),  
                        yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),  
                        margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20),
                        height=100,
                        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                        xaxis_showgrid=False,
                        yaxis_showgrid=False,
                        xaxis_zeroline=False,
                        yaxis_zeroline=False,
                    ),
                    config={'displayModeBar': False}
                )
            ]
        ),
        style={"width": "18rem", "margin": "10px"}
    )

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Causes"),
        dbc.Row(
            [dbc.Col(generate_card(failure_cause, proba_cause, rank), width=4) 
             for rank, (failure_cause, proba_cause) in enumerate(zip(df['failure_cause'], df['proba_cause']), 1)]
        )
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

which gives

You also mentioned graduation for the probabilites. Not sure if you meant gauges, but here is how to achieve that:
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'failure_cause': ['Cause 1', 'Cause 2', 'Cause 3', 'Cause 4', 'Cause 5'],
    'proba_cause': [0.5767, 0.1923, 0.0648, 0.0502, 0.0502]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def generate_card(failure_cause, proba_cause, rank):
    return dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H4(f"{failure_cause}", className="card-title"),
                html.P(
                    f"{round(proba_cause*100, 2)}%",
                    className="card-text",
                ),
                html.P(
                    f"rank: {rank}",
                    className="card-text",
                ),
                dcc.Graph(
                    figure=go.Figure(go.Bar(
                        x=[proba_cause * 100],
                        y=[failure_cause],
                        orientation='h',
                        marker=dict(
                            color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.6)',
                            line=dict(
                                color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 1.0)',
                                width=1),
                        ),
                    )),
                    config={'displayModeBar': False}
                )
            ]
        ),
        style={"width": "18rem", "margin": "10px"}
    )

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Causes"),
        dbc.Row(
            [dbc.Col(generate_card(failure_cause, proba_cause, rank), width=4) 
             for rank, (failure_cause, proba_cause) in enumerate(zip(df['failure_cause'], df['proba_cause']), 1)]
        )
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)



which gives (N.B. Not full image)

